# How to protect a domain address without owning a company?

Tags: trademark

I have recently bought the perfect domain address for a company I plan to start in Brazil some years down the road. One complication is that I currently live in the UK.

I have searched the WIPO's registry and I dont believe I'm violating anyones trade mark.

What is the best way for me to protect this domain and right to use the company name, to avoid a future trade mark claim?

WIPO allows me to register an international trademark, but they say I should have a "basic mark" done in my "home IP" office before. So, what I think makes sense is that, I file a UK trade mark as an individual, and then use it to file an international trade mark that then would apply to Brazil.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking, trademark law does not allow to reserve a trademark for future use for an extended period of time (like five years), without using it. A trademark arises from use in commerce or imminent intended future use in commerce.

Comment: That’s a very good point. I appreciate it. For clarity, I’m releasing an app using the domain soon, and I intend to stabilish a company in the next 3 years :)